# Call Javascript onClick not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, onclick

```
         *@ JAVASCRIPT
             $(document).ready(function()
             {
             }
             )

             function videochange(url) {
                 alert(url)
             }
```

On the click of this button it wont hit the JavaScript function above. Any idea why? I really need to get that video.Value to a JavaScript function.....

```
 @foreach(var video in Model.VideoList)
        {           
            var url = video.Value;
         <input type="button" value="@video.Text" onclick="javascript:videochange(url);" />
            <br />
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach(var video in Model.VideoList)
{           
    var url = video.Value;
 <input type="button" value="@v.Value" onclick="@String.Format("videochange('{0}')", url)" />
    <br />
}
```

Comment: the funny thing is this worked at one point now its giving me the undetermined string constant again... and the second ' seems to not realize theres a first ' it makes the ); after count as the string.

Answer (score 2):

I would use JQuery. Assuming you've got version 1.7 or later, the following code should work. It also enforces a better separation between your markup and your JavaScript.

```
<div class="container">
  @foreach(var video in Model.VideoList) {           
    <input type="button" value="@video.Text" data-url="@video.Value" />
  }
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(){
      var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
      alert(url);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd probably add `[data-url]` to the button selector, so only buttons with a data-url get that click handler.

Comment: @cHao Yeah, that's even better.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@foreach(var video in Model.VideoList) {           
    <input type="button" value="@video.Text" onclick="videochange('@video.Value');" />
    <br />
}
```

Comment: @CoreyToolis sorry updated, there was another error. `onclick="javascript:videochange` should be `onclick="videochange`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: The `javascript:` thing is ugly, but not a syntax error.  It gets parsed as a label.

Comment: the funny thing is this worked at one point now its giving me the undetermined string constant again... and the second ' seems to not realize theres a first '
it makes the ); after count as the string.